# Tarantool storage lock warnings when call multiple get/update of the same row

Tags: tarantool

I have a vinyl space with some entities, that are linked between themselves by some application logic. Insert/update of any entity needs some calculations and update of linked entities too.

Let's say we have some entities with ids: `e1, e2, e3 ... eN, eK`

Update of any entity is made by such code:

```
function updateEntity(eN) then
  space:update(eN)
  
  if eN linked to eK then
    -- Update linked entity eK and do some calculations.
    local eK = space:get('eK')

    -- Calculations using eK (time consuming)
    ...

    -- Modify linked entity eK
    space:update(eK)

    -- Some other calculations (time consuming)
    ...

    -- Using linked entity eK later somewhere else.
    local eKAgain = space.get('eK')
  end
end
```

`updateEntity()` is exposed to global (`box.schema.func.create('updateEntity')` + `rawset(_G, 'updateEntity', updateEntity)`) and is called from outside by nodejs connector.

**Problem:**
When I call `updateEntity()` very frequently for entities that are linked with the same entity `eK`, I have multiple warnings like
`get(['eK']) => ... took too long: 150.879 sec.`
The value of 'stuck' time vary form 1 to 1500 sec! So, obviously I have some storage locks or something like that.

**Questions:**

1. How it can happen anyway? I thought Tarantool is one threaded, so if I call `updateEntity()`, then the other call of `updateEntity()` can be possible only if the first one is finished?
2. Can I sovle this problem using fibers, calling each `updateEntity()` as different fiber and making all inner operations with `cK` entity like transaction? Or I misunderstand fibers purpose?
3. Maybe problem somewhere else and I miss something?

Comment: Are you using memtx or vinyl engine for this space?

Answer (score 0):

Vinyl engine supports multiversion concurrency control by default, you can read about it [here](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/book/box/atomic/) in more details